# sparseIndexTracking 0.1.0 failure in if(): missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r, xts, na, zoo

I have two datasets. Both are `xts` objects.

```
 > dput(head(all_data[,2:3]))
    structure(c(0.00108166576527857, 0.00324149108589955, 0, 0, 0.00484652665589658, 
    0.00267952840300101, 0.00606980273141122, 0.00301659125188536, 
    0.00526315789473686, -0.00149588631264019, 0, -0.00299625468164799
    ), class = c("xts", "zoo"), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    ), .indexTZ = "UTC", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC", index = structure(c(1453716060, 
    1453716120, 1453716180, 1453716240, 1453716300, 1453716360), tzone = "UTC", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), .Dim = c(6L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("ClosePrice_AGL.1", 
    "ClosePrice_AMC")))

> dput(head(all_data[,1]))
    structure(c(0.00108166576527857, 0.00324149108589955, 0, 0, 0.00484652665589658, 
    0.00267952840300101), class = c("xts", "zoo"), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "UTC", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC", index = structure(c(1453716060, 
    1453716120, 1453716180, 1453716240, 1453716300, 1453716360), tzone = "UTC", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), .Dim = c(6L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "ClosePrice_AGL"))

> dput(head(mydata_train[,1:3]))
    structure(c(-0.00155763239875384, -0.0279251170046803, -0.00225324987963404, 
    -0.000479333950998528, 0.0042195179257094, -0.00163456299477571, 
    -0.00526315789473697, -0.0222222222222221, -0.00431818181818178, 
    -0.00218475886131686, 0.00217864923747269, -0.00217391304347825, 
    -0.00651612903225807, -0.0221442950840964, -0.00385177314384377, 
    0.00333333333333319, -0.00365448504983379, -0.0160053351117039
    ), class = c("xts", "zoo"), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    ), tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "", index = structure(c(1527255180, 
    1527256080, 1527256260, 1527256440, 1527256800, 1527256980), tclass = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), .Dim = c(6L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("ACBFF.Close", 
    "APHQF.Close", "WDDMF.Close")))

> dput(head(mydata_train[,4]))
    structure(c(0.00429610046265694, -0.00789733464955589, -0.00165837479270303, 
    -0.00299003322259139, 0.00333222259246901, -0.00199269345732311
    ), class = c("xts", "zoo"), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    ), tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "", index = structure(c(1527255180, 
    1527256080, 1527256260, 1527256440, 1527256800, 1527256980), tclass = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), .Dim = c(6L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "MJ.Close"))
```

and I am running `spIndexTrack` from:

```
library(sparseIndexTracking)

  test <- spIndexTrack(all_data[,2:3] , all_data[,1], lambda = 1e-7, u = 0.5, measure = 'ete')

  test <- spIndexTrack(mydata_train[,1:3] , mydata_train[,4], lambda = 1e-7, u = 0.5, measure = 'ete')
```

The second function gives:

```
 w
ACBFF.Close 0.47083543
APHQF.Close 0.42967200
WDDMF.Close 0.09949257
```

but the first fails:

```
Error in if (abs(a + 1) < 1e-06) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I have no `NA`s

```
all_data <- all_data[complete.cases(all_data),]

any(is.na(all_data) == TRUE)
```

and all my data is numeric.

```
storage.mode(my_data) <- "numeric"
```

I can run a regression through with no errors:

```
lm(all_data[,1] ~ all_data[,2:3])
```

It's not a result of having 0s in my data frame

```
all_data[all_data==0] <- 1e-9
```

Tried wrapping as matrix:

```
as.matrix(all_data)
```

Don't know what has gone wrong.

---

If anyone wants to run the full working example with online google/yahoo data you can with:

```
library(sparseIndexTracking)
library(xts)
library(gquote)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)

#######################################
############  SET PARAMETERS  #########
#######################################

# Data

minute_interval <- 3
n_periods <- 10000




#######################################
############  GET DATA  #########
#######################################


# pull yahoo / google data for the portfolio (2 stocks)

mydata <- merge(getIntradayPrice('ACBFF', period=n_periods, interval = minute_interval),
                getIntradayPrice('APHQF', period=n_periods, interval = minute_interval),
                getIntradayPrice('WDDMF', period=n_periods, interval = minute_interval),
                getIntradayPrice('MJ', period=n_periods, interval = minute_interval),
                getIntradayPrice('HMLSF', period=n_periods, interval = minute_interval)
)

#select just closing prices
mydata <- mydata[,c(1,6, 11, 16)]


# remove NA values

mydata <- mydata[complete.cases(mydata),]

# replace all with returns of the two series - can use 'log' or 'discrete'
mydata <- Return.calculate(mydata, method = 'discrete')


# remove NA values again

mydata <- mydata[complete.cases(mydata),]

## split set into first 50% training data second 50% test data

mydata_train <- mydata[1:floor(nrow(mydata) * 0.5),]
mydata_test <-  mydata[floor(nrow(mydata) * 0.5 +1):nrow(mydata),]


# remove NA values again

mydata_train <- mydata_train[complete.cases(mydata_train),]

# Generate weights see : https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sparseIndexTracking/vignettes/SparseIndexTracking-vignette.pdf



w_ete <- spIndexTrack(mydata_train[,1:3] , mydata_train[,4], lambda = 1e-7, u = 1.5, measure = 'ete')
w_ete
```

I'm stuck. Not sure if anyone can help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Data preparation**

`spIndexTrack` first applies `as.matrix` on your input object as the function expects a matrix and a vector

```
 spIndexTrack(X, r, lambda, u = 1, measure = c("ete", "dr", "hete", "hdr"),
   hub = NULL, w0 = NULL, thres = 1e-09)
```

Arguments:

```
   X: m-by-n matrix of net returns (m samples, n assets).

   r: m dimensional vector of the net returns of the index.
```

So for simplicity you can just `dput(datamat <- as.matrix(all_data))`, which is

```
datamat <- 
structure(c(0.00108166576527857, 0.00324149108589955, 0, 0, 0.00484652665589658, 
0.00267952840300101, 0.00108166576527857, 0.00324149108589955, 
0, 0, 0.00484652665589658, 0.00267952840300101, 0.00606980273141122, 
0.00301659125188536, 0.00526315789473686, -0.00149588631264019, 
0, -0.00299625468164799), .Dim = c(6L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(
c("2016-01-25 10:01:00", "2016-01-25 10:02:00", "2016-01-25 10:03:00", 
"2016-01-25 10:04:00", "2016-01-25 10:05:00", "2016-01-25 10:06:00"
), c("ClosePrice_AGL", "ClosePrice_AGL.1", "ClosePrice_AMC"
)))
```

Then set

```
X <- datamat[, 2:3]
r <- datamat[, 1]
```

---

**Identify the problem**

Note that `X[, 1]` and `r`  are identical:

```
identical(X[, 1], r)
#[1] TRUE
```

You can run an `lm(r ~ 0 + X)`, but as `r` can be perfectly explained by `X[, 1]`, coefficient for `X[, 2]` ends up being zero:

```
XClosePrice_AGL.1    XClosePrice_AMC  
        1.000e+00         -6.346e-19
```

According to [SparseIndexTracking vignette: explanation of the algorithms](https://rawgit.com/dppalomar/sparseIndexTracking/master/vignettes/SparseIndexTracking-vignette.html#explanation-of-the-algorithms), `spIndexTrack` is doing a **contrained least squares with lasso-alike regularization**.

- Regression coefficients must be non-negative and sum up to 1, so that they give a valid portfolio;
- Regularization imposes a sparse variable selection.

For the above `X` and `r`, the non-contrained ordinary least squares already gives you the best sparse portfolio: `(1, 0)`. What else would you expect `spIndexTrack` to do?

```
## your call to `spIndexTrack`
spIndexTrack(X, r, lambda = 1e-7, u = 0.5, measure = 'ete')
```

In particular, you set `u = 0.5`, which requires any portfolio weight to be no larger than `0.5`. Given that the optimal weight vector are `(1, 0)`, the algorithm might have a big struggle.

I think you'd better not change the default value `u = 1`. This default means that the algorithm is able to shrink all but one feature to zero.

Now even the following would fail.

```
spIndexTrack(X, r, lambda = 1e-7, u = 1, measure = 'ete')
```

Therefore I plan to set the regularization to zero, i.e., `lambda = 0`, but it still fails. I have to set it to a tiny negative to make it work:

```
spIndexTrack(X, r, lambda = -1e-16, u = 1, measure = 'ete')
#                            w
#ClosePrice_AGL.1 9.999996e-01
#ClosePrice_AMC   3.633128e-07
```

And as you can see, the result is close to `(1, 0)`.

---

**Lack of numerical stability of the package**

I checked this package on CRAN. As of today (2018-07-30) it is still in its first release (version 0.1.0).

By glancing the R code of `spIndexTrack` I found that basically no test for numerical stability is made. The error you get is just because you get an `0 / 0` hence an `NaN` for variable `a`.

I am not interested to go through the mathematical algorithms to think about what prior numerical tests should be made. The following suggestion is the most robust, but probably too restricted, but the other working example in your question (associated with `mydata_train`) satisfies this condition.

- `X` has full rank, that is, `qr(X)$rank` equals to `ncol(X)`;
- `cbind(X, r)` has full rank, that is, `lm(r ~ 0 + X)` does not end up with all-zero residuals.

It is the package author's responsibility to consider this. But in the end, the function should first check for numerical failure and return an early informative error.

Comment: Hi. never got to give you a proper thank you for this. thanks for taking the time to reply. i have reverted to using this package again and once again your post herehas been a great hep